# How to access the index with pandas DataFrame apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use DataFrames `apply` with `axis=1` (so, for each row), and use the row's index. I can't seem to do that.

This is (kinda) what I'd like to get:

`objects = df.apply(lambda x: DB.fetch(x['index']), axis=1)`

So, I think the underlying question is: What object is passed to the function given to `apply`? (I know I can reset the index, but I'm trying to understand a point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` passes the row as a Series when you use `axis=1`. This means that the Index of the DataFrame becomes the `name` attribute of that Series.

```
print(df)
   data  grouping_col
a     3             2
b     3             2
c     1             3
d     2             1
e     2             2

df.apply(lambda row: row.name, axis=1)
#a    a
#b    b
#c    c
#d    d
#e    e
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative would be to apply your function directly to your dataframe's index column using .map(). Assuming DB.fetch is a function that takes an integer (i.e. an index value):

```
objects = df.index.map(lambda x: DB.fetch(x))
```

Should do what you are trying to do, if I understand correctly.